# Как сделать скрывающееся меню при изменении размера, JS CSS @media

Tags: javascript, css

Есть шаблон http://purecss.io/layouts/email/
Хочу его использовать в своем проекте под embed устройство, соответственно места очень мало + не будет инета.
Этот темплейт тянет почти 170кб js файлов с jquery не легче будет - 90 кб.
Мне всего-то и нужно - чтобы при изменении размера меньше определенного - меню становилось вверху и показывалось по нажатию кнопки.
Я в JS очень плохо разбираюсь, вот такой код на сколько адекватен под задачу?

```
(function (window, document) {

var layout   = document.getElementById('layout'),
    menu     = document.getElementById('menu'),
    menuLink = document.getElementById('menuLink');

function toggleClass(element, className) {
    var classes = element.className.split(/\s+/),
        length = classes.length,
        i = 0;

    for(; i < length; i++) {
      if (classes[i] === className) {
        classes.splice(i, 1);
        break;
      }
    }
    // The className is not found
    if (length === classes.length) {
        classes.push(className);
    }

    element.className = classes.join(' ');
}

menuLink.onclick = function (e) {
    var active = 'active';

    e.preventDefault();
    toggleClass(layout, active);
    toggleClass(menu, active);
    toggleClass(menuLink, active);
};

}(this, this.document));
```

Если можно - подскажите как правильно использовать в моем случае?

```js
(function (window, document) {

    var layout   = document.getElementById('layout'),
        menu     = document.getElementById('menu'),
        menuLink = document.getElementById('menuLink');

    function toggleClass(element, className) {
        var classes = element.className.split(/\s+/),
            length = classes.length,
            i = 0;

        for(; i < length; i++) {
          if (classes[i] === className) {
            classes.splice(i, 1);
            break;
          }
        }
        // The className is not found
        if (length === classes.length) {
            classes.push(className);
        }

        element.className = classes.join(' ');
    }

    menuLink.onclick = function (e) {
        var active = 'active';

        e.preventDefault();
        toggleClass(layout, active);
        toggleClass(menu, active);
        toggleClass(menuLink, active);
    };

}(this, this.document));
```

```css
/*
 * -- BASE STYLES --
 * Most of these are inherited from Base, but I want to change a few.
 */
body {
    color: #333;
}



a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #1b98f8;
}


/*
 * -- HELPER STYLES --
 * Over-riding some of the .pure-button styles to make my buttons look unique
 */
.primary-button,
.secondary-button {
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
.primary-button {
    color: #fff;
    background: #1b98f8;
    margin: 1em 0;
}
.secondary-button {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    color: #666;
    padding: 0.5em 2em;
    font-size: 80%;
}

/*
 * -- LAYOUT STYLES --
 * This layout consists of three main elements, `#nav` (navigation bar), `#list` (email list), and `#main` (email content). All 3 elements are within `#layout`
 */
#layout, #nav, #list, #main {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* Make the navigation 100% width on phones */
#nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    background: rgb(37, 42, 58);
    text-align: center;
}
/* Show the "Menu" button on phones */
#nav .nav-menu-button {
    display: block;
    top: 0.5em;
    right: 0.5em;
    position: absolute;
}

/* When "Menu" is clicked, the navbar should be 80% height */
#nav.active {
    height: 80%;
}
/* Don't show the navigation items... */
.nav-inner {
    display: none;
}

/* ...until the "Menu" button is clicked */
#nav.active .nav-inner {
    display: block;
    padding: 2em 0;
}


/*
 * -- NAV BAR STYLES --
 * Styling the default .pure-menu to look a little more unique.
 */
#nav .pure-menu {
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
}
    #nav .pure-menu-link:hover,
    #nav .pure-menu-link:focus {
        background: rgb(55, 60, 90);
    }
    #nav .pure-menu-link {
        color: #fff;
        margin-left: 0.5em;
    }
    #nav .pure-menu-heading {
        border-bottom: none;
        font-size:110%;
        color: rgb(75, 113, 151);
    }


/*
 * -- EMAIL STYLES --
 * Styles relevant to the email messages, labels, counts, and more.
 */
.email-count {
    color: rgb(75, 113, 151);
}

.email-label-personal,
.email-label-work,
.email-label-travel {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.email-label-personal {
    background: #ffc94c;
}
.email-label-work {
    background: #41ccb4;
}
.email-label-travel {
    background: #40c365;
}


/* Email Item Styles */
.email-item {
    padding: 0.9em 1em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-left: 6px solid transparent;
}
    .email-avatar {
        border-radius: 3px;
        margin-right: 0.5em;
    }
    .email-name,
    .email-subject {
        margin: 0;
    }
    .email-name {
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: #999;
    }
    .email-desc {
        font-size: 80%;
        margin: 0.4em 0;
    }

.email-item-selected {
    background: #eee;
}
.email-item-unread {
    border-left: 6px solid #1b98f8;
}

/* Email Content Styles */
.email-content-header, .email-content-body, .email-content-footer {
    padding: 1em 2em;
}
    .email-content-header {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    }

        .email-content-title {
            margin: 0.5em 0 0;
        }
        .email-content-subtitle {
            font-size: 1em;
            margin: 0;
            font-weight: normal;
        }
            .email-content-subtitle span {
                color: #999;
            }
    .email-content-controls {
        margin-top: 2em;
        text-align: right;
    }
        .email-content-controls .secondary-button {
            margin-bottom: 0.3em;
        }

    .email-avatar {
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
    }


/*
 * -- TABLET (AND UP) MEDIA QUERIES --
 * On tablets and other medium-sized devices, we want to customize some
 * of the mobile styles.
 */
@media (min-width: 50em) {

    /* Move the layout over so we can fit the nav + list in on the left */
    #layout {
        padding-left:750px; /* "left col (nav + list)" width */
        position: relative;
    }

    /* These are position:fixed; elements that will be in the left 500px of the screen */
    #nav, #list {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    #nav {
        margin-left:-750px; /* "left col (nav + list)" width */
        width:150px;
        height: 100%;
    }

    /* Show the menu items on the larger screen */
    .nav-inner {
        display: block;
        padding: 2em 0;
    }

    /* Hide the "Menu" button on larger screens */
    #nav .nav-menu-button {
        display: none;
    }
    
    #list {
        margin-left: -600px;
        width:600px;
        height: 100%;
        border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
    
    #main {
        position: static;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    

}
```

```html
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/pure-min.css">
<div id="layout" class="content pure-g">
    <div id="nav" class="pure-u">
        <a href="#" class="nav-menu-button">Меню</a>

        <div class="nav-inner">
            <div class="pure-menu">
                <ul class="pure-menu-list">
                    <li class="pure-menu-heading">set</li>
                    <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Состояние</a></li>
                    <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Настройка сети</a></li>
                    <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Настройка<br>устройства</a></li>
                    <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Об устройстве</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="list" class="pure-u-1">
        <div class="email-item email-item-selected pure-g">
            <div class="pure-u">
                <img class="email-avatar" alt="Tilo Mitra&#x27;s avatar" height="64" width="64" src="img/common/tilo-avatar.png">
            </div>

            <div class="pure-u-3-4">
                <h5 class="email-name">Tilo Mitra</h5>
                <h4 class="email-subject">Hello from Toronto</h4>
                <p class="email-desc">
                    Hey, I just wanted to check in with you from Toronto. I got here earlier today.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="email-item email-item-unread pure-g">
            <div class="pure-u">
                <img class="email-avatar" alt="Eric Ferraiuolo&#x27;s avatar" height="64" width="64" src="img/common/ericf-avatar.png">
            </div>

            <div class="pure-u-3-4">
                <h5 class="email-name">Eric Ferraiuolo</h5>
                <h4 class="email-subject">Re: Pull Requests</h4>
                <p class="email-desc">
                    Hey, I had some feedback for pull request #51. We should center the menu so it looks better on mobile.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="email-item email-item-unread pure-g">
            <div class="pure-u">
                <img class="email-avatar" alt="YUI&#x27;s avatar" height="64" width="64" src="img/common/yui-avatar.png">
            </div>

            <div class="pure-u-3-4">
                <h5 class="email-name">YUI Library</h5>
                <h4 class="email-subject">You have 5 bugs assigned to you</h4>
                <p class="email-desc">
                    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit essecillum dolore eu fugiat nulla.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="email-item pure-g">
            <div class="pure-u">
                <img class="email-avatar" alt="Yahoo! Finance&#x27;s Avatar" height="64" width="64" src="img/common/yfinance-avatar.png">
            </div>

            <div class="pure-u-3-4">
                <h5 class="email-name">Yahoo! Finance</h5>
                <h4 class="email-subject">How to protect your finances from winter storms</h4>
                <p class="email-desc">
                    Mauris tempor mi vitae sem aliquet pharetra. Fusce in dui purus, nec malesuada mauris.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="email-item pure-g">
            <div class="pure-u">
                <img class="email-avatar" alt="Yahoo! News&#x27; avatar" height="64" width="64" src="img/common/ynews-avatar.png">
            </div>

            <div class="pure-u-3-4">
                <h5 class="email-name">Yahoo! News</h5>
                <h4 class="email-subject">Summary for April 3rd, 2012</h4>
                <p class="email-desc">
                    We found 10 news articles that you may like.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="main" class="pure-u-1">
        <div class="email-content">
            <div class="email-content-header pure-g">
                <div class="pure-u-1-2">
                    <h1 class="email-content-title">Hello from Toronto</h1>
                    <p class="email-content-subtitle">
                        From <a>Tilo Mitra</a> at <span>3:56pm, April 3, 2012</span>
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div class="email-content-controls pure-u-1-2">
                    <button class="secondary-button pure-button">Reply</button>
                    <button class="secondary-button pure-button">Forward</button>
                    <button class="secondary-button pure-button">Move to</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="email-content-body">
                <p>
                    Lorem 
                </p>
                <p>
                    Duis 
                </p>
                <p>
                    Aliquam 
                </p>
                <p>
                    Donec

                </p>
                <p>
                    Regards,<br>
                    Tilo
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="js/yui-b62.js"></script>
<script src="js/combo-b62.js"></script>

<script>
    YUI().use('node-base', 'node-event-delegate', function (Y) {

        var menuButton = Y.one('.nav-menu-button'),
            nav        = Y.one('#nav');

        // Setting the active class name expands the menu vertically on small screens.
        menuButton.on('click', function (e) {
            nav.toggleClass('active');
        });

        // Your application code goes here...

    });
</script>
```

Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю задачу, то тут вообще можно без скриптов обойтись. При какой ширине нужно изменить меню?

Comment: по-факту надо прости при изменении размера переместить меню вверх и показывать его по нажатию кнопки. я планировал где-то 40-50em, т.к. сейчас чисто по пикселям не получится из-за мобильных устройств, у меня у смарта ширина 1440px